What is the message inflation ratio in ring-LWE?
I've been learning and implementing standard ring-LWE over $R_t = \mathbb{Z}_t[x]/(x^N+1)$ [1]. In my implementation [2] the inflation ratio is ~192 (it takes 192 bytes to encrypt 1 byte). My parameters are $t=2^8$ (plaintext modulus), $q=2^{15}$, $N=2^4$. Here
$192 = 5\cdot 16 \cdot 2 + 32$
since $q = 32768$ is five digits and there are two degree 16 polynomials and comma separators. This would imply in general the ratio is $ \approx 2 N\log_{10}(q)$. Is that correct?
My understanding is we're encrypting a single integer $m$ which gets mapped to a constant polynomial $m \in R_t$. There are two polynomials in $R_t$, say $v = ar + e_2$ and $w = br + e_3 + km$ where $r$ is the ephemeral key, $e_2,e_3$ are (carefully chosen) noise. So $km \approx t$ and multiplying by $k$ shifts m to be the "highest bit" above the noise so it can be recovered after multiplying by the secret key and subtracting. The ciphertext is $(v,w)$, so the ratio would be $(\text{len}(v)+\text{len}(w))/\text{len}(m)$.

[1] https://math.colorado.edu/~kstange/teaching-resources/crypto/RingLWE-notes.pdf
[2] https://github.com/jacksonwalters/open-encrypt


RLWE is not secure using your ring $R_t$. This ring splits $R_t \cong \mathbb{Z}_t[x] / (g(x)) \times \mathbb{Z}_t[x] / (x-1)$ for a polynomial $g(x)$ (this is because $x^N-1$ has a root at $x = 1$). You can therefore take $(a(x), b(x))$ and evaluate at $x = 1$ to reduce to a 1D (integer) LWE sample $(a(1), b(1))$ with noise of standard deviation $\approx\sqrt{n}$ times larger. This 1D LWE instance is trivial to break.

As for your question (with $R_t$ replaced with $\mathbb{Z}_t[x] / (x^{2^k}+1)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$), the answer is "it depends". For large enough messages you should be able to achieve expansion factor $2 + \epsilon$ (where $\epsilon$ goes to 0 as message size goes to infinity) using standard techniques. See for example Section 3.4 of this paper. I've also written this paper on a similar topic, though details are only spelled-out in the private-key case.

Also, in general you can encrypt not only $m\in\mathbb{Z}_t$, but an entire message polynomial $m(x)\in R_t$. This already yields ratio $\approx$ $2\log_t(q)$, but as mentioned you can make this smaller with various techniques.

@MarkSchultz-Wu I've seen both $x^N-1$ and $x^N+1$ used as a polynomial modulus, and I guess there's some sloppiness here, as we're really working over $\mathbb{Z}_t[x]/(\Phi(x))$. However that is definitely a typo! In both my implementation (pulled from https://blog.openmined.org/build-an-homomorphic-encryption-scheme-from-scratch-with-python/) and Stange's notes they use $x^N+1$. Edited.

@MarkSchultz-Wu I wanted to use an entire polynomial for a message, but I was worried as both implementations (Stange's notes and the linked one) just use single integers. I wasn't sure why they did that. You're saying one can just use $N$ coefficients at once with no restrictions?

Yes, you can encrypt message polynomials. The only restriction is that rather than the message itself being small, all coordinates of the message must be small simultaneously, but this is not that large of a restriction. The bigger issue for minimizing the expansion factor is that there is a minimum ring degree one must use for security. For particular numbers people use the lattice estimator, but $\approx 500-700$ is typical. If you want to encrypt less data than this there will be some "wasted space"

@MarkSchultz-Wu That's very helpful, thank you. I need to play with the parameters, but if I understood correctly the expansion factor is $\approx 2\log_t(q)$, which doesn't depend on $N$?

That's correct, but expansion factor only matters when you want to send some large amount of data. For a small amount of data (say a 128-bit PRF key, for hybrid encryption), you can't achieve nearly as small of expansion factor. This is because you can achieve expansion factor $2\log_t(q)$ for messages that are $N\log_2(t)$ bits, but for smaller messages there may be some amount of "wasted space" in your message space.

@MarkSchultz-Wu I see. In my demo I'd like to encrypt longer messages. At present, I'm only able to encrypt ~41 characters (the SQL column is max 8000 characters right now). It sounds like I can get the expansion factor way down by using the whole polynomial with small coefficients since the message would then indeed be $N\log_2(t)$ bits.

Yeah that should work. There are other tricks you can do too (roughly speaking --- carefully analyze the noise in the ciphertext, and use certain lossy forms of compression that introduces additional noise that still can be corrected later), but they're a little more mathematically complex to do, so aren't worth considering initially.

@MarkSchultz-Wu Success! The inflation ratio is down to ~13.71 now. I haven't worried about checking the sizes of coefficients yet - it seems to decrypt all messages I've tried. The ints are utf-8 encodings, so 7 bit strings as ints, and $q=2^{15}$ is relatively large I suppose. Yes, for now the more mathematically complex methods will have to wait, perhaps until I've made this more user-friendly. Thanks for your help.
